# Symfony - Exception 'Key "xy" for array with keys "0, 1, .." does not exist.' when using twig's title function

Tags: php, function, variables, twig

I am trying to display the play name from the specified table but I get an error

> Key "playName" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5" does not exist.

I know what the error is about but I cant figure out what to do next.

```
public function playTicketsAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Play')
        ->findAll();

    $build['playName'] = $query;

    return $this->render('@FrontTemplates/pages/tickets.html.twig', array(
        'playName' => $build
    ));
}
```

and in twig

```
<div class="card-header card-header-warning">
    {% for t in playName %}
    <h4 class="card-title ">{{ t.playName }}</h4>
    {% endfor %}
    <p class="card-category"> Here you can choose available ticket category</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to replace : `$build['playName'] = $query;` by `$build = $query`

Comment: It's a pogress but now it returns all 5 names form table not the specific one?

Comment: Well change this too : `{% for t in playName %} <h4 class="card-title ">{{ t }}</h4>
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: I add a response, I think you add 2 problem : first was the array you pass from php to your template twig, second was your twig var name. I have no information about what `AppBundle:Play` return but I think you want to display the column `playName` of each row you get, right? But your array in twig as the same name...try my solution and tell me if it's ok for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There's this example about the for tag with assosiative array:

```
<div class="card-header card-header-warning">
{% for t in playName.playName %}
<h4 class="card-title ">{{ t }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
<p class="card-category"> Here you can choose available ticket category</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `$build['playName'] = $query;` by `$build = $query;`.

Then change your Twig var name :

```
return $this->render('@FrontTemplates/pages/tickets.html.twig', array(
    'query_result' => $build // change it so it's not "playName"
));
```

Your Twig var `{{ query_result }}` will be an array, the result of your query.

Now in your Twig template, just do :

```
{% for t in query_result %}
    <h4 class="card-title ">{{ t.playName }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you will get the `playName` column name of each row your got with your query.

Before, you were doing :

```
{% for t in playName %}
    <h4 class="card-title ">{{ t.playName }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

So you add an array `playName` and you wanted to display `{{ t.playName }}` : playName was your Twig name array, not a column name of each row so you got two different thing with similar name.

Is it ok for you?

Comment: It still returns all five names.. Not specified one.. :/

Comment: Did you change: the var name in your PHP and in your Twig template? If it didn't works, please can you edit your question and add the result of `var_dump($query);` to see what you pass in your Twig template?

Comment: Yes I did. It returns PlayController.php on line 47:
array:6 [▼
  0 => Play {#1126 ▶}
  1 => Play {#1047 ▶}
  2 => Play {#1113 ▶}
  3 => Play {#1077 ▶}
  4 => Play {#1082 ▶}
  5 => Play {#1086 ▶}
]

Comment: Now I added in my query ->find($playId); and it returns specific name. How to add it to twig?

Comment: I can't see what's inside `Play` here...in your Twig template, `t` is equal to what's inside `Play`, right?

Comment: If you do `->find($playId)` you now have one row and no more 5 rows, no? I don't know how your data looks like it's hard for me to guess what you are doing and what you want !

Comment: playId returns what it should.. Its PlayController.php on line 46:
Play {#1125 ▼
  #id: 1
  -playName: "Fantom iz Opere"
  -theater: Theater {#1114 ▶}
  -hall: Hall {#1075 ▶}
  -date: DateTime 1537488000 {#1116 ▶}
  -time: DateTime 73800 {#1128 ▶}
  -status: "PUBLISHED"
  -amount: null
  #preSeparator: "("
  #separator: ", "
  #postSeparator: ")"
  #allowedClasses: []
  #parts: []
} and now I need to pass playName to twig by this id

Comment: I'm sorry what you ask is not clear...just get your data  in PHP -> pass the data in Twig as you did before -> if it's an array do your loop and foreach loop display the current "playName"...I can't debug your code for you, if if the Twig for loop `t` is a row with `playName = XXX` it should display XXX. If not, your data have an other format. Maybe it's `t['playName']`, maybe `t[0].playName`, you are the one who know !